# Byte Buddy: Create implementation for an abstract class

Tags: java, class, interface, bytecode, byte-buddy

I would like to create an implementation at runtime for an abstract class using Byte Buddy and I'm facing the issue, that a `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` is being thrown when invoking a method from a created instance. I have an existing `abstract` class like this (which I actually cannot modify and which actually contains more logic):

```
public abstract class Algorithm {
    abstract int execute();
}
```

Using the following minimal sample, I would like my `Algorithm` instance to return a constant value:

```
Class<?> type = new ByteBuddy()
                        .subclass(Algorithm.class)
                        .method(ElementMatchers.named("execute"))
                        .intercept(FixedValue.value(42))
                        .make()
                        .load(classLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                        .getLoaded();
Algorithm instance = (Algorithm) type.newInstance();
System.out.println(myInstance.execute());
```

This however leads to the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: package.Algorithm.execute()I
```

(when I experimentally change `Algorithm` to an `interface`, everything works fine, but this does not solve my specific issue).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It might surprise you but the exact same thing would happen if you had generated the same code using *javac* using the same class loader setup. What you observe is implied by how package-privacy is specified in the JLS. Your **non-interface** class

```
public abstract class Algorithm {
  abstract int execute(); 
}
```

defines a package-private method. Since you do not define a custom name for the generated class, Byte Buddy generates a subclass with a random name that lives in the same package. Byte Buddy does further discover the `executable` method as overridable from the generated subclass and implements it exactly as you would expect it to.

However, you are using the `ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER` strategy to load the class which creates a new child-class loader of the one loading `Algorithm`. In Java, **at runtime**, two packages are however **only equal if the name of the package is equal and both packages are loaded by the same `ClassLoader`**. The later condition is not true for your case such that the JVM does no longer apply polymorphism to the `execute` class. By calling

```
((Algorithm) type.newInstance()).execute();
```

you are therefore not invoking the generated method but the original, abstract method. Therefore - in accordance to the JLS - an `AbstractMethodError` is thrown.

To fix this problem, you either need to load the generated class in the same package, using the default `INJECTION` strategy or you have to define `execute` as a `public` (this is implicit when defining an interface) or `protected` method such that the rules for polymorphism that you expect do apply. As a third option, you could invoke the correct runtime method by

```
type.getDeclaredMethod("execute").invoke(type.newInstance());
```

Comment: Thank you Rafael for your very detailed explanation, as chance will have it, I just discovered two minutes ago, that the root of my issue was caused by the fact, that the abstract method was package private. The `INJECTION` is my solution. Btw, great job on Byte Buddy!